# Android Studio: what's causing logcat battery power supply logs?

Tags: android, android-studio, device, logcat, smartphone

I have an Android smartphone connected to my Mac using a USB cable. When running Android Studio, the following appears in the LOGCAT. These lines continually repeat, sometimes in a slightly different order. It's not clear to me what's causing this and how I can fix it...

```
08-09 16:17:31.554 2208-20167/? D/NetlinkSocketObserver: NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=11269730, 192.168.1.254, [5464D91A00EE], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_STALE}
08-09 16:17:32.829 27970-27970/? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
08-09 16:17:32.830 27970-27970/? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
08-09 16:17:37.856 27971-27971/? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
08-09 16:17:37.857 27971-27971/? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
08-09 16:17:42.881 27972-27972/? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
08-09 16:17:42.882 27972-27972/? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
08-09 16:17:47.901 27973-27973/? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
08-09 16:17:47.902 27973-27973/? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
```

Comment: obviously is not from your app .. seems like bug in motorola firmaware

Comment: yes my apps test fine so far on the motorola - it's just annoying and clogs up my logcat

Comment: @Selvin So good to hear there is a bug in device and not in our code.
I am using MotoG and facing the problem. The above mentioned log runs till I click the installed app. Once the app is started this log is not displayed.

Comment: I'm also seeing this on a Moto G3

Comment: Moto E Gen 2 4G here.

Comment: Are you able to deploy the app? The Android Monitor in Android Studio does not stop displaying these two errors and I can't deploy the app on the device (Moto 3G). Thanks