# Cannot run on production devices

Tags: android, root

When I run my application, the message below is printed in the error log.  I don't understand if the problem is from my application or if the message is printed by my Android device.

```
E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
```

I read this answer [Unable to run 'adb root' on a rooted Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369144/unable-to-run-adb-root-on-a-rooted-android-phone) , but my device is not rooted.

Why this error log is printed ?

Comment: It does not seem related to your app, but just log entry from your device (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854778/android-studio-whats-causing-logcat-battery-power-supply-logs)

Comment: ok, antur you have idea why this log print

Comment: I've found that message when launching my application in device too. as @antur123 says, this is not related to our app at all. I found no error when testing my production app from playstore.

Comment: "Power Off" & then "Power On" worked for me.

Comment: bug in motorola devices

Answer (score 0):

The main problem (I believe) that causes this, is your mobile's battery.

When Motorola mobiles have low battery, and they're connected to a computer, the USB option for the mobile will be forced to charging only mode.

To solve this, just swipe down from the top, click the **USB for charging, touch for more options** and select File Transfer. This will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling this function: go to **Settings** -> **Security** Just activate **Unknown sources**.

Now that you're ready to install your apk.

Answer (score -1):

Try to active Developer Mode on setting of your device.

> #### Enable Developer Options In Android 6.0 Marshmallow
>
> 1. Pull down on the notifications shade and open the *Settings* app. You can also achieve the same thing from the app drawer if you so wish.
> 2. Scroll all the way down and tap on ‘*About phone*’.
> 3. Now scroll down again and you’ll see an entry labelled ‘*Build number*’. Keep on tapping till you see a prompt that says ‘*You are now a developer!*’