# E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start and E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me what is this reason print below error, when app is running and launching below logs is print.

> Device is Moto G3, Marshmallow api level 23,

```
09-14 14:53:14.482 ? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
09-14 14:53:14.484 ? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
09-14 14:53:19.509 ? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
09-14 14:53:19.511 ? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
09-14 14:53:24.535 ? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
09-14 14:53:24.536 ? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
09-14 14:53:27.862 ? D/NetlinkSocketObserver: NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=66401695, 192.168.1.1, [001EA60E4CEC], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_STALE}
09-14 14:53:29.562 ? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
09-14 14:53:29.564 ? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
09-14 14:53:34.589 ? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
09-14 14:53:34.589 ? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
09-14 14:53:39.614 ? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
09-14 14:53:39.615 ? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
09-14 14:53:44.637 ? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
09-14 14:53:44.638 ? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
09-14 14:53:46.102 ? D/NetlinkSocketObserver: NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=66419935, 192.168.1.1, [001EA60E4CEC], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_STALE}
09-14 14:53:49.665 ? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
09-14 14:53:49.666 ? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
09-14 14:53:54.691 ? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
09-14 14:53:54.691 ? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
09-14 14:53:59.715 ? E/NEW_BHD: Battery Power Supply logging Daemon start!!!!!
09-14 14:53:59.716 ? E/NEW_BHD: Cannot run on production devices!
```

response is appreciated !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854778/android-studio-whats-causing-logcat-battery-power-supply-logs

Comment: Seems to be a known issue with Motorola phones, nothing you should be worried about.

Answer (score -2):

I am using moto g3 turbo.. for me also same error. this answer is worked for me..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39468763/5933300...i run my app in debug mode and then go to Run ----> Attach debugger to Android process ----> then popup will open in that u choose ur project and give ok..then it will come to debug mode

enter image description here

[image: image description here]

[image]